# Count rows returned by subquery

Tags: sql

Let's say I have this table named `tblsample`

[image]

I'm trying to get the number of `codes` unique to each `title`. So the result should be `abc = 3` and `def = 3`

My query right now is

```
Select T1.title, COUNT(tbl2.code) as [No. of Codes]
from (Select t2.title, T2.CODE from tblsample as T2 where T2.category = 'com' group by t2.title, t2.CODE) AS tbl2
inner join tblsample as T1 on (T1.title = tbl2.title)
where T1.category = 'COM'
group by T1.title
order by T1.title
```

But it's returning `abc = 15` and `def = 9` so I'm quite confused. Where am I wrong here?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the query as simple as this will do:

```
Select title, COUNT(DISTINCT code) as [No. of Codes]
from tblsample 
where category = 'COM'
group by title
order by title
```

Comment: Dayum that did the trick and it's so simple! I didn't know you can use distinct like that. Thanks @cha!